# Function returns table based on other function's returned data

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, postgresql-9.4

I have a function defined as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_1() RETURNS TABLE (
    column_1 text,
    column_2 text,
    -- large number of other returned columns
    -- ...
) AS
$$
BEGIN
    -- Something done here
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Is it possible to declare a `func_2`, which will use the same returned table structure as `func_1` (data returned from `func_1` will be used internally by `func_2`)?

Of course, I could essentially copy and paste the declaration, but then if anything changes in the table structure returned from `func_1` I would have to manually keep `func_2` in sync. One way would be to refactor the `func_1` to return a composite type and make `func_2` return the same type as well - but is it possible to keep using the `RETURNS TABLE` and make another function depend on it "seamlessly"?

Comment: You're saying that you want to create a 2nd function but would be used in the first function?

Comment: On the contrary, the second function should basically return the same data as the first one (as in - do some operations, then select data from the first function and return it).

Comment: So you want to return the data from `func_2` which is data from `func_1`, if table structure from `func_1` changes then `func_2` table structure must also be changed accordingly. So, what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: The question is - is there a way to define `func_2` somehow that it's NOT necessary to update it manually when `func_1` table changes.

Comment: There is a way I thought but requires a lot of coding. Basically, you create a view of `func_1`. Then in your `func_2`, it will return a set of that view & you will need to get the column names & their datatype, you can refer from here: [link](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94049/how-to-get-the-data-type-of-each-column-from-a-postgis-table)[link] then cast into text/varchar & include them into dynamic sql strings which contain code for `REPLACE VIEW`  of `func_1` according to current table structure in  `func_1`

Answer (score 0):

As @Joshua pointed out above, you can set up a dependency between these functions by exploiting the fact that every table and view comes with a free composite type:

```
CREATE FUNCTION f() RETURNS TABLE (x INT) LANGUAGE sql AS 'VALUES (1)';
CREATE VIEW v AS SELECT * FROM f();
CREATE FUNCTION g() RETURNS SETOF v LANGUAGE sql AS 'VALUES (2)';
```

`g()` now depends on the return type of `f()`. Though if you were hoping to change the return type of `f()` and have it propagate through, you're out of luck:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f() RETURNS TABLE (x INT, y INT) LANGUAGE sql AS 'VALUES (3,3)';
```

> ERROR:  cannot change return type of existing function
>
> HINT:  Use DROP FUNCTION f() first.

And then, of course:

```
DROP FUNCTION f();
```

> ERROR:  cannot drop function f() because other objects depend on it
>
> DETAIL:  view v depends on function f()
>
> function g() depends on type v
>
> HINT:  Use DROP ... CASCADE to drop the dependent objects too.

If you want to redefine a function return without dropping it completely, I think you're going to need to create a composite type.